# C++ Build environment on Windows

Tags: build, makefile, msys, tdm-mingw, tdm-gcc

It might be hard to believe but I still struggle to completely understand what a build environment is. I have gathered over the years that it is a directory tree within which my compiler can find all the necessary **headers** and **lib** files to build my projects.. I never really learned this concept properly and gained a basic understanding of it only recently.

I'm using a TDM-GCC 64bit compiler, MSYS, Windows 7 64bit.

When I build my libraries for use in my projects they all place header and lib files into my C:\mingw directory.. ie.. C**:\mingw\include & C:\mingw\lib**

Let's say I'm building zlib. The zlib directory will contain both the lib and include headers and my root c:\mingw directory will **also** contain the zlib headers and lib files in these directories the c:\mingw\include & c:\mingw\lib directory.

So when I'm building other libraries that need zlib as a dependancey, I initially used the below command:
**./configure --prefix = c:\mingw**   and when I build it using the '**make**'  command (all in MSYS), my new library can find all it's dependencies in the c:\mingw\include & c:\mingw\lib directory.    **Have I done this correctly?**

**Here's where I get confused.**    When I am writing up my projects in my CodeBlocks IDE which uses the same compiler TDM-GCC 64bit, do I set the search directories to the c:\mingw\include & c:\mingw\lib directories **or do I use the zlib directory** **c:\zlib\include and c:\zlib\lib directory?**

Or..... Should I have placed the entire zlib directory inside the c:\mingw directory so that my file path looks like this:
**c:\mingw\zlib\include & c:\mingw\zlib\lib directories**.

If I'm wrong about all of the above, how do I set up a robust build environment on windows?

Also.... to supplement this gap in my knowledge, is there any book/textbook which explains this kind of thing well?

I have decided against using cygwin for now.

Lots of questions ;)

Thanks, sorry for the long spiel.

*******Late addition below*************

I placed a test file in c:\ming and using my cmd line I called the command
**gcc -v test.h**    (test.h is the test file I placed in my root directory to test the search path of my compiler.
Here's the output:

As you can see, when using --prefix, the other include directory at: 
**C:/mingw/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include**   is ignored.
I'm wondering why the mingw compiler has done this.

The file I'm having trouble getting my compiler to search for (math.h) is not even in the include directory.

```
C:\mingw\include>gcc -v test.h
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../../../src/gcc-5.1.0/configure --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --enable-targets=all --enable-languages=ada,c,c++,fortran,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-libgomp --enable-lto --enable-graphite --enable-cxx-flags=-DWINPTHREAD_STATIC --disable-build-with-cxx --disable-build-poststage1-with-cxx --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-threads=posix --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libstdcxx-threads --enable-libstdcxx-time --with-gnu-ld --disable-werror --disable-nls --disable-win32-registry --prefix=/mingw64tdm --with-local-prefix=/mingw64tdm --with-pkgversion=tdm64-1 --with-bugurl=http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/bugs
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.1.0 (tdm64-1)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 C:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/cc1.exe -quiet -v -iprefix C:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/ -D_REENTRANT test.h -quiet -dumpbase test.h -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase test -version -o C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cco9AQmC.s --output-pch=test.h.gch
GNU C11 (tdm64-1) version 5.1.0 (x86_64-w64-mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 5.1.0, GMP version 4.3.2, MPFR version 2.4.2, MPC version 0.8.2
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring duplicate directory "C:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "C:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../include"
ignoring duplicate directory "C:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include-fixed"
ignoring duplicate directory "C:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 C:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include
 C:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../include
 C:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include-fixed
 C:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include
End of search list.
GNU C11 (tdm64-1) version 5.1.0 (x86_64-w64-mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 5.1.0, GMP version 4.3.2, MPFR version 2.4.2, MPC version 0.8.2
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 72fdcf42c4c1c584c8e1347f320364c3
In file included from pngconf.h:30:0,
                 from test.h:422:
C:/mingw/include/limits.h:32:23: fatal error: tr1/climits: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

C:\mingw\include>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak about your build environment, but I can clarify a few points.

On *nix systems, when you build (zlib, per your example) with `configure --prefix=$PREFIX`, headers are installed under `$PREFIX/include` and libraries are installed under `$PREFIX/lib`. The "zlib directories" you mention should not exist if you built zlib configured with `--prefix='c:\mingw'`. Rather, there should exist both

```
c:\mingw\include\zlib.h
c:\mingw\lib\libz.so
```

or something similar.

To build something that depends on zlib installed like this, you should have the former in your `CPPFLAGS` as an `-I` include path, and the latter in your `LDFLAGS` as a `-L` library path.

I would encourage you to reference the GNU Make manual and the GNU coding standards for help understanding system conventions like these.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on reading GNU Make and GNU Coding.. I have the GNU make manual but not the Coding Standards so just glancing through this answers allot of questions.         The reason I asked this question is that people always ask me to describe my build environment and I am not always clear on what they mean.   I currently have a problem where I have included a math.h file and t references the system math.h file via usr/include/math.h on windows.  This then should default to the C++ include directory, but it doesn't.   I'm trying to understand the ins and outs of this so I can fix it.

Comment: @Svetsi, yeah, you have my sympathy. "Build environment" is *very* overloaded. It can refer to the "toolchain triplet", the toolchain itself, the platform underneath, the IDE in use (if any), the project directory structure, environment variables, and so on *ad nauseum*. If the problem you're trying to solve encompasses an entire project, I would suggest putting it into public source control; e.g., github, gitlab, bitbucket.

Comment: thanks rubicks.. I'm slowly understanding this. In relation to your answer above (your first answer), I'm running into some build issues and have been told that that's a result of my build environment.. I'll post another question on that anyway.. Cheers